# How to use datagrid in sending an sms to each value in a row in a specific column. VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm new to Vb6. I just want to know how to use my sms code to send all the numbers in the rows in a specific column. In this code, the messages i received are more than what i want to receive. Please help me fix my looping method.

```
Dim x As String
Dim e As Integer
Dim allcontacts As String

For i = 0 To DataGrid1.VisibleRows
    For e = 0 To DataGrid1.ApproxCount - 1

    allcontacts = DataGrid1.Columns(5).CellValue(DataGrid1.GetBookmark(e))


    ' Send an 'AT' command to the phone
    MSComm1.Output = "AT" & vbCrLf
    Sleep 500
    MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf     'This line can be removed if your modem will always be in Text Mode...
    Sleep 500
    MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & allcontacts & Chr(34) & vbCrLf   'Replace this with your mobile Phone's No.
    Sleep 1000
    MSComm1.Output = "From School Activities Management System: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The time now is " & Label3.Caption & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Announcement:" & vbCrLf & Text1.Text & Chr(26)
    Sleep 2000


    Next e
Next i

x = DataGrid1.VisibleRows
MsgBox "Message Sent to " + x + " contacts in faculty."
End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of the datagrid:
[image: filled Datagrid screenshot]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you need a double loop.  Currently, for every visible row you are looping through all rows.  Is that your intent?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention.
Basically, using all the values of a row of a specific column of the datagri with that SMS code.

Comment: You don't seem to use the loop variable i in your code anywhere. This seems wrong. Why again do you need the nested loops?

Comment: Sorry for bad coding sir. I really do think there's no need for a double loop.
Can you suggest me a code that uses only 1 loop that loops for all the visible rows, and uses the SMS codes for specific column's rows?
(5 is the specific column's index)

Comment: Perhaps if you include a screenshot of a filled in grid that would help us propose a solution.

Comment: I have added the screenshot at the edited thread above for you convenience sir, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your screenshot, it looks like you want to send 1 sms for each row.  Therefore, I would try the following code:

```
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim allcontacts As String

   For i = 0 To DataGrid1.VisibleRows - 1
      allcontacts = DataGrid1.Columns(5).CellValue(DataGrid1.GetBookmark(i))

      ' Send an 'AT' command to the phone
      MSComm1.Output = "AT" & vbCrLf
      Sleep 500
      MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf     'This line can be removed if your modem will always be in Text Mode...
      Sleep 500
      MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & allcontacts & Chr(34) & vbCrLf   'Replace this with your mobile Phone's No.
      Sleep 1000
      MSComm1.Output = "From School Activities Management System: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The time now is " & Label3.Caption & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Announcement:" & vbCrLf & Text1.Text & Chr(26)
      Sleep 2000
   Next i

   MsgBox "Message Sent to " & DataGrid1.VisibleRows & " contacts in faculty."
```

One thing to keep in mind is that messages will only be sent for those rows that are visible on the screen.  If they are scrolled off the screen and can't be seen then no message will be sent.

Comment: Yay, i sended the message in both the contacts that i have but there's a problem.
I receive an "Invalid row number" error and it highlights the "allcontacts = DataGrid1.Columns(5).CellValue(DataGrid1.GetBookmark(i))" code.
I wonder what's the problem?

Comment: The loop should be for VisibleRows - 1.  I will modify the sample code.

Comment: Adding -1 to the visiblerows did removed the error however, the message just only sended the first row.
I just confirmed it by interchanging the numbers and the result is i only received message from the first row.

Comment: I am not sure of the issue.  I ran the same code here and it sent 2 messages.

Comment: It's funny because i just run out of load for texting!
Yes, it works! Thank you! Thumbs up